# Python create dictionary from dataframe in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

first post!

I am trying to create a function that create dictionary in loop from a dataframe.
Assume those 2 simplistic dataframes already exist:

```
data1 = {'A':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'B':[5, 6, 7, 8]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

dataframe1

[image: 1]

and

```
data2 = {'C':[9, 10], 'D':[11, 12], 'E':[13, 14] }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

dataframe2

[image: 2]

I want to be able to create a function like this:

```
def create_dict(df):
```

where the end results of df1 is:

```
dict1 = { 'A' : 1, 'B' : 5}
dict2 = { 'A' : 2, 'B' : 6}
dict3 = { 'A' : 3, 'B' : 7}
dict4 = { 'A' : 4, 'B' : 8}
```

and the end results of df2 is:

```
dict1 = { 'C' : 9, 'D' : 11, 'E' : 13}
dict2 = { 'C' : 10, 'D' : 12, 'E' : 14}
```

I was looking at dictionary comprehension to handle this, but I'm obviously not sure how to handle that problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` with `records`:

```
df1.to_dict(orient="records")
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 1, 'B': 5}, {'A': 2, 'B': 6}, {'A': 3, 'B': 7}, {'A': 4, 'B': 8}]
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, beautiful and simple!